# How can I use the inject() function for a source component, by using a Java Class?

Tags: java, anylogic

I want a source component to produce an agent with source.inject() , but I have to call this method from a foreign Java class at the projects sidebar on the left. I am new to Anylogic and I don't have much programming experience. I don't know how I can correctly refrence the source.

Comment: We need more details of your expected behavior , for getting a suitable answer, please try to ask your question with more details and clear as it possible i.e try to share some codes and details of source.inject() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Java class ("in the side bar") needs to have a private field `myMain` of type `Main`. In its constructor, add that field as an argument and fill it as usual with Java.

When you initialize an instance of your class, provide it `main` as well (depends on where in your model you initialize).

If this sounds like gibberish, I strongly suggest you take a step back, learn more advanced OOP, Java and how AnyLogic applies that :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to follow your suggestions! It's been awhile since I learned about OOP and Java at my university, so you are right. After reading your solution I  was annoyed that I didn't think of that. :D

Comment: Great. Please flag the answer as useful (up-arrow next to it) so other users can find it more easily in the future ;) @Helamir